# image viewer using css is not working

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hello Friends,

I am trying to develop a simple image viewer as you can see in given picture i want when user hover on black box then the red box will appear i got problem on the last div when user hover on last div the red div going outside please help me . Is there any way to solve this using `CSS` only. Please see my code

**CSS**

```
div{float:left; text-align:center; font-size:16px; color:#404040; margin:0 30px 20px 30px; position:relative;

    .viewer{
        position:absolute;
        width:300px;
        background:red;
        height:400px;
        top:20px;
        left:110px;
    }
```

Thanks in advance .. :)

Comment: The red box is doing EXACTLY what your code defines. `left:110px` is the culprit. Changing it to `right: 110px` won't fix it as the first box will then be cut off on the left side. Just use javascript at this point.

Comment: Thanks for comment @ProfileTwist will you please share any javascript or jquery exaple i am doing right now but its hard for me to find the solution plz help..

Answer (score 0):

I redid this for you. Try this and you should be good. It looks like you have your relative and absolute positioning mixed up.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Begin Image Hover -->
<ul class="enlarge">
    <!-- First Image -->
    <li>
        <img src="image.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" alt="Dechairs" /><span><img src="image.jpg" alt="Deckchairs" /><br />Deckchairs on Blackpool beach</span>
    </li>
    <!-- Second Image -->
    <li>
        <img src="image.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" alt="Blackpool sunset" /><span><img src="image.jpg" alt="Blackpool sunset" /><br />Sunset over the Irish Sea at Blackpool</span>
    </li>

    <!-- Third Image -->
    <li>
        <img src="image.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" alt="Blackpool pier" /><span><img src="image.jpg" alt="Blackpool pier" /><br />Rolling waves off Blackpool North Pier</span>
    </li>
</ul> <!-- End Image Hover -->
```

**And now CSS...**

```
ul.enlarge{
    list-style-type:none; /*remove the bullet point*/
    margin-left:0;
    }

ul.enlarge li{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    margin:10px 40px 0 20px;
    }

ul.enlarge img{
    background-color:#eae9d4;
    padding: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    }

ul.enlarge span{
    position:absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    background-color:#eae9d4;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #495a62; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0, .75));
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
    border-radius:8px;
    }

ul.enlarge li:hover{
    z-index: 50;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

ul.enlarge span img{
    padding:2px;
    background:#ccc;
    }

ul.enlarge li:hover span{ 
    top: -300px;
    left: -20px;
    }

ul.enlarge li:hover:nth-child(2) span{
    left: -100px; 
    }

ul.enlarge li:hover:nth-child(3) span{
    left: -200px; 
    }

/**IE Hacks - see http://css3pie.com/ for more info on how to use CS3Pie and to download the latest version**/
ul.enlarge img, ul.enlarge span{
    behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc); 
    }
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/u2BAh/) so you can see how it works...

Comment: Thanks for help but the problem is still remaining scollbar still coming. I want to enlarge the image without any scrollBar

Comment: Any chance you can post your code somewhere so we can look at it. It's always a lot easier that way. Use [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: for your reff just see this page http://www.scribbler.com/bestsellers and hover the fourth card you can see that enlarge div appear left side not right side like others..

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what you want then. In your original image, your far-right image bleeds over and creates a horizontal overflow. But, take a look at this image [here](https://app.box.com/s/uiykvy5p1lcs31hr9yer)... I see no overflow. What browser are you using?